# Creating node with weight in java graph

Tags: java, algorithm, graph

I am creating a program to create a graph for bibliography dataset. The graph is directed, has Author node and Paper node, and has 2 types of edges (author to paper edge, paper to paper edge).

I want to get an input from you about whether or not what I am creating is making sense. Right now, it produces the right result when I want to get the outEdge and inEdge from and to a node. But im not sure if this implementation is correct in terms of the methods, designs, and algorithm.

Also, I have a problem with assigning weight to a node. I want to ask how can I do this as well. Right now, what I have tried is as follows:

```
for (String item : CandidateAuthorType1Unique) {
    double weight = Collections.frequency(CandidateAuthorType1, item);
    n.setWeight(item,weight);;
    System.out.println(n.getName() + " : " + n.getWeight());
}
```

However, after using `setWeight`, the `getName()` method returns null. This means that the weight assigned is not assigned to a certain item. I wonder how to update the weight a certain item.

If I use

```
for (String item : CandidateAuthorType1Unique) {
    double weight = Collections.frequency(CandidateAuthorType1, item);
    n = new Node(item,weight);
    System.out.println(n.getName() + " : " + n.getWeight());
}
```

Does it mean that each time a new node n is created, the old n node will not be stored? How can I checked every node ever created and its weight?

I would like to ask for your input to this program. Any input would be really helpful for me. Thank you.

**Main class: Ranker.java**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.sql.*;

public class Ranker {

    static Graph g;
    static Node n;
    static Edge e;
    static HashMap nodeMap;   // maps Integer NodeIDs to Node object
    String id;
    double weight;

    Ranker() {
            g = new Graph();
            nodeMap = new HashMap();
            n = new Node(id,weight);
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, IOException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException{

        Ranker Ranker = new Ranker();
        Connection connect = null;
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        HashMap nodeMap =  new HashMap();   // maps Integer NodeIDs to Node objects

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/arnetminer?"+"user=root&password=1234");
        preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement("Select fr,t,ty from subedge");

        resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        int i=0;

        while(resultSet.next()) {
           g.addEdgeForIndexing(resultSet.getInt(1),resultSet.getInt(2),resultSet.getInt(3));
           i++;             
           System.out.println( "edges added to G = "+i);
        }       

        System.out.println("Loaded " + g.nodeCount() + " nodes.");

        buildNodes();

        System.out.println("Enter first author key:");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String authorkey1 = br.readLine(); 
        int authorID1 = Integer.parseInt(authorkey1);
        String AuthorID1 = "A"+authorID1;
        ArrayList<String> p1 = g.getOutEdgesToP(AuthorID1);
        System.out.println("P1 = " + p1);

        ArrayList<String> p2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int j = 0; j<p1.size();j++){
            ArrayList<String> temp = g.getOutEdgesToP(p1.get(j));
            if (temp!=null)
            p2.addAll(temp);
        }
        System.out.println("P2 = " +p2);

        ArrayList<String> CandidateAuthorType1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int k = 0; k<p2.size(); k++){
            ArrayList<String> temp = g.getInEdgesFromPtoA(p2.get(k));
            if(temp!=null)
                CandidateAuthorType1.addAll(temp);
        }
        System.out.println("Candidate Author Type 1= " + CandidateAuthorType1);

        ArrayList<String> CandidateAuthorType1Unique = removeDuplicates(CandidateAuthorType1);
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Candidate author type 1 and author node weight:");
        for (String item : CandidateAuthorType1Unique) {
            double weight = Collections.frequency(CandidateAuthorType1, item);
            n.setWeight(item,weight);;
            System.out.println(n.getName() + " : " + n.getWeight());
        }       

        ArrayList<String> CandidatePaperType1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int l = 0; l<CandidateAuthorType1.size(); l++){
            ArrayList<String> temp = g.getOutEdgesToP(CandidateAuthorType1.get(l));
            if(temp!=null)
                CandidatePaperType1.addAll(temp);
        }
        System.out.println("Candidate Paper Type 1= " + CandidatePaperType1);
    }   


    private static ArrayList<String> removeDuplicates(ArrayList<String> element){
        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<>();
        for (String item : element) {
            if (!set.contains(item)) {
            result.add(item);
            set.add(item);
            }
        }
        return result;  
    }

    private static void buildNodes() 
    {
        String nodeID;
        double weight = 0;
        Node n;
        Iterator it = g.nodeIteratorInitial();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
          nodeID = (String) it.next(); 
          if (!nodeMap.containsKey(nodeID)){
              n = new Node(nodeID,weight);
              nodeMap.put(nodeID, 0);
          }
        }
    }
}
```

**Graph.java**

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.*;

public class Graph {

    private HashSet<String>  nodeIDs;   
    public HashMap<Integer, String> nodeIDsWithTN;
    public HashMap<Integer, String> TNMap;  
    private HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>  edges;
    private HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>  reverse;
    private int numNodes;
    private int numEdges;
    private int numReverse;

    public Graph() {
        edges = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
        reverse = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
        nodeIDs = new HashSet<String>();
        nodeIDsWithTN = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        TNMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        new HashSet();
    }

    public void addEdgeForIndexing(int from, int to, int T) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
        String From = ""+from;
        String To = ""+to;
        int type = T; 
        if(T==1)
        {
            From="A"+from;
            To="P"+to;
        }
        else if(T==2)
        {
            From="P"+from;
            To="P"+to;
        }           
        else
            System.out.println("T ="+T+" value undefined");

            Edge e = new Edge(From,To,type);

            nodeIDs.add(e.From);
            nodeIDs.add(e.To);

            ArrayList<String> tmp = null;
            if (edges.containsKey(e.From))
              tmp = (ArrayList<String>) edges.get(e.From);
            else {
              tmp = new ArrayList<String>();
              edges.put(e.From,tmp);
            }
            tmp.add(e.To);

            ArrayList<String> tmp2 = null;
            if (reverse.containsKey(e.To))
              tmp2 = (ArrayList<String>) reverse.get(e.To);
            else {
              tmp2 = new ArrayList<String>();
              reverse.put(e.To,tmp2);
            }
            tmp2.add(e.From);
    }

    public int nodeCount() {
        if(nodeIDs.size() > 0) 
            return nodeIDs.size();
            // else return numNodes;
        return numEdges;
    }

    public int countInEdges(Integer key) {
        if (!reverse.containsKey(key)) return 0;
            return ((ArrayList<?>) reverse.get(key)).size();
    }

    public int countOutEdges(Integer key) {
        if (!edges.containsKey(key)) return 0;
            return ((ArrayList<?>) edges.get(key)).size();
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getInEdgesFromPtoA(String id) {
        if (!reverse.containsKey(id)) return null;  
            ArrayList<String> a = reverse.get(id);
            ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
                for(int j=0;j<a.size();j++){
                      if(a.get(j).startsWith("A")){
                          result.add(a.get(j));                           
                      }
                 }
        return result;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getOutEdgesToP(String id) {
        if (!edges.containsKey(id)) return null;    
            ArrayList<String> a = edges.get(id);
            ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
            for(int j=0;j<a.size();j++){
              if(a.get(j).startsWith("P")){
              result.add(a.get(j));                           
              }
            }
        return result;
    }

    public Iterator<String> nodeIteratorInitial() {
        return nodeIDs.iterator();
    }
}
```

**Edge.java**

```
public class Edge {


    String From;
    String To;
    int type;
    private static int counter = 0;
    public Edge(String From, String To, int type) {
        this.From = new String(From);
        this.To = new String(To);
        this.type = type;
    //  System.out.println("edges added from " + From + " to " +  To + " with type "+ type);
    }

    public String getFrom(){
        return From;
    }

    public String getTo(){
        return To;
    }

    public int getType(){
        return type;
    }

    public void setFrom(String From){
        this.From = From;
    }

    public void setTo(String To){
        this.To = To;
    }

    public void setType(int type){
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

**Node.java**

```
public class Node {

      String id;
      double weight;
      private static int counter = 0;

      public Node(String id,double weight) {
          this.id = id;
          this.weight = weight;;

      }

      public double getWeight(){
            return weight;
      }

      public String getName() {
           return id;
      }

      public void setWeight(String id, double weight){
         if (this.id==id){
          this.weight=weight;}
          System.out.println("The node " + id + " has weight " + weight);
      }


      public void setName(String id){
          this.id=id;
      }

}
```

Comment: As you have asked recommendations on design, I find having id parameter on setWeight strange. Because of that it also involves checking of id inside. Better to get node by Id and then execute setter on that.

Comment: the reason I use id parameter is to be able to update a weight of a certain node id. Can I ask how to get node by id as you suggested?

Comment: You are using a map 'nodemap' to store nodes you are creating. Instead of just storing ids you store <key= nodeid, value=node> then when you are required to get node, query this map, get node by id and update weight on it. So, that way you add weight to the correct node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are initialising `n` in the `Ranker()` constructor, when the constructor is called, the `String id` has not been assigned and therefore always contains the value `null`. Therefore your `Node n` also gets the `id` as `null`. This is the reason why the weight isn't updated as in your `setWeight(String id, double weight)` function, the new `id` is compared to `null` which always returns `false` therefore the weight doesn't get updated.

You could make the following changes in your code

1) Remove the `n = new Node(id,weight)` initialisation in your `Ranker()` constructor.

2) Add the following lines instead of `n.setWeight(item,weight)` in your `main` method in `Ranker` class.

```
if (n == null)
    n = new Node(item, weight);
n.setWeight(item, weight);
```